# Product ID should not be accessed directly

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, error-handling

I recently updated wordpress and PHP on my testing server. I have fixed a lot of the errors but this one is stumping me. On my shop page, my thumbnails stopped appearing. My products and prices are still showing up correctly. Here is the error message 
`Notice: id was called incorrectly. Product properties should not be accessed directly.`

Here is the PHP

```
<?php
    $placeholder_width = $placeholder_height = 400;
                $url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($product->ID), array(260,260) );
                if ( has_post_thumbnail() ){?>

                  <?php   if ( is_plugin_active( 'woocommerce-lazyload/woocommerce-lazyload.php' )) {?>
                          <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($posts->ID) ?>"> <img data-src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($posts->ID , ['220','220']); ?>" class="attachment-220x220 size-220x220 wp-post-image" width="300" height="300"></a>
                    <?php }else{ ?>
                            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($posts->ID) ?>"> <img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($posts->ID , ['220','220']); ?>" class="attachment-220x220 size-220x220 wp-post-image"></a>
                    <?php }?>
                    <?php
                }
                else {
                    echo '<img src="'. woocommerce_placeholder_img_src() .'" alt="Placeholder" width="' . $placeholder_width . '" height="' . $placeholder_height . '" />';
                }

            ?>
```

This chunk is where the problem is. I tried to remove the if statement and jsut have the image and URL grab. I tried to convert `$product->ID` to `$product->get_id()` and the latter actually takes the error message away but my thumbnails are not showing up. It must be getting postID correct because the names and prices are showing up and being categorized accordingly. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try using `$product = wc_get_product($post->ID);` before calling the $url variable. After that `$product->ID` should work just fine.

Comment: Since WooCommerce3, simply try to replace `$product->ID` with `$product->get_id()`. It should work.